# Error: The method 'Style.textStyle' has fewer positional arguments than

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**Error is**

> The method 'Style.textStyle' has fewer positional arguments than those
> of overridden method 'StyleHook.textStyle'. TextStyle textStyle(Color
> color)

**Here is the problem** `@override TextStyle textStyle(Color color) { return TextStyle(color: color);`

[image: THE SCREENSHOT]

```
class Style extends StyleHook {
  @override
  double get activeIconSize => 28;

  @override
  double get activeIconMargin => 10;

  @override
  double get iconSize => 20;

  @override
  TextStyle textStyle(Color color) {
    return TextStyle(color: color);
  }

}
```

Comment: What don't you understand? It says exactly what's wrong

Comment: You just posted the code for `Style` twice, but not posted anything for `StyleHook`.

Comment: `class Style extends StyleHook {
  @override
  double get activeIconSize => 28;

  @override
  double get activeIconMargin => 10;

  @override
  double get iconSize => 20;

  @override
  TextStyle textStyle(Color color) {
    return TextStyle(color: color);
  }

}`

Comment: @Ivo  Error: The method 'Style.textStyle' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'StyleHook.textStyle'.
  TextStyle textStyle(Color color) {

Answer (score 0):

Your error says exactly what's wrong. `StyleHook` expects a `Color` and a `String?` as argument for the `textStyle` function. You extend `StyleHook` and override that function but are not providing the same arguments for it. It needs to look like

```
TextStyle textStyle(Color color, String? s) {
```

Comment: but still show error

Comment: @MuhammadArafat try `flutter clean` and rebuild the  app

Comment: @YeasinSheikh still show error

Comment: If you are using `convex_bottom_bar` and this solution doesnt, consider including more details(+version) a widget that will reproduce the same issue