# isn't a valid override of 'StyleHook.textStyle

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Error is

> The method 'Style.textStyle' has fewer positional arguments than those
> of overridden method 'StyleHook.textStyle'. TextStyle textStyle(Color
> color)

[image: screenshot]

> 'Style.textStyle' ('TextStyle* Function(Color*)*') isn't a valid
> override of 'StyleHook.textStyle' ('TextStyle Function(Color,
> String?)').

Flutter Channel stable, 3.0.0

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.2 <3.0.0"

**Here is the problem** @override TextStyle textStyle(Color color) { return TextStyle(color: color);

```
class Style extends StyleHook {
  @override
  double get activeIconSize => 28;

  @override
  double get activeIconMargin => 10;

  @override
  double get iconSize => 20;

  @override
  TextStyle textStyle(Color color) {
    return TextStyle(color: color);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you include your flutter and package version

Comment: Flutter Channel stable, 3.0.0  environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.2 <3.0.0"

Comment: and what are using for `StyleHook `

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Actually my team member write the code, now he left

Comment: Here is the code google drive link you can download. [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zDPY57muVKIIok2a-P1o78KaHmiiu1G_?usp=sharing)

Comment: actually the project size might be within 20 mb, consider removing build folder then zip it, or git repo better

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Ok Bhai I will try asap

Comment: Just include the pubspec.yaml, I may get it

Answer (score 1):

if you have similar problem like this, just add `String? fontFamily` parameter **OR** add `throw UnimplementedError();`

textStyle override look like this :

```
...
  
  @override
  TextStyle textStyle(Color color, String? fontFamily) {
    
    // TODO: implement textStyle
    // ...

    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

...
```

if you need a return from textStyle override, you can modify like this :

```
...

  @override
  TextStyle textStyle(Color color, String? fontFamily) {
    // TODO: implement textStyle
    return TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: color);
  }

...
```

Hopefully this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using convex_bottom_bar.
The solution was posted at the following URL and I followed it and it solved the problem.

[Error: The method 'Style.textStyle' has fewer positional arguments than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73787723/error-the-method-style-textstyle-has-fewer-positional-arguments-than)

I looked at the StyleHook definition and found that a String type was optionally specified, so I changed it to accept it as shown below, and the error did not occur.

```
class Style extends StyleHook {
    @override
    double get activeIconSize => 30;

    @override
    double get activeIconMargin => 5;

    @override
    double get iconSize => 24;

    @override
    TextStyle textStyle(Color color, String s) {
        return TextStyle(
            fontSize: 11,
            color: Colors.white,
        );
    }
}
```